# How to install Gimp and next remove it from terminal!

Tags: command-line, software-installation, gimp

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS version. I am trying to install the newest version of Gimp 2.8.18, from gimp.org/download at http://download.gimp.org/mirror/pub/gimp/v2.8/ . How do I install it. I watched this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=njqib0fzE9c

Is this the correct path, because ever-time I try I am having complications.
What is your step by step for 14.04 for bz2 installation process. I would really apperciate it, Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You DO NOT at all need to compile a package from source if you already have a `.deb` package for it. Why go through the hassle when someone else has already done all the hardwork for you?

It's like your dinner is already there in a restaurant that provides cheap, hygienic, tasty food with the desired menu for their customers minus the hardwork that goes into making the food and then washing the dishes later but still you want to make your own dinner.

So, to install the latest `gimp` package in Ubuntu, do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp -y; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install gimp
```

---

**EDIT:-** [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/ubuntu/gimp) website proof of the above mentioned `ppa`.

You can also validate the above website, by doing a quick google search - `gimp ppa`.

Comment: Where does this information of repository come from. Since it is the easiest method. Can you provide a website. Thank You

Comment: @RonnieMarlow - Edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to kill an ant with a hammer. As the bz2 notes:

> ```
> ******************************************************************
> * Unless you are experienced with building software from source, *
> * you should not attempt to build all these libraries yourself!  *
> * We suggest that you check if your distributor has development  *
> * packages of them and use these instead.                        *
> ******************************************************************
> ```

Gimp is already in the default software repos, so you can just run an `apt` command to install it:

```
sudo apt install gimp
```

which will, in turn, install the GIMP package through the official software repository, and allow `apt` to manage updates with all of the other packages.

---

If you actually want to build from source (which GIMP themselves say is not a good idea -- unless you actually *need* the bleeding edge), you're gonna need to extract the archive:

```
mkdir gimp-2.8/
cd gimp-2.8/ 
wget https://download.gimp.org/mirror/pub/gimp/v2.8/gimp-2.8.18.tar.bz2
tar xvf gimp-2.8.18.tar.bz2
```

This will create a new folder, likely called `gimp-2.8.18` in the current directory. `cd` into that, and then:

1. Run `chmod +x ./configure`
2. Run `./configure`
3. If `./configure` returns any errors, fix them until it says everything's okay.
4. Run `make` to actually build the latest version of GIMP.
5. If everything returns okay, run `sudo make install` to actually install GIMP.

Note that this method of installation may not bind filetypes, and it also might not make menu shortcuts, requiring you to manually call `gimp` from the terminal.

Comment: Yeah, that is part of the question. But the Ubuntu Software Store has the Gimp version 2.8.10 version I believe. What is the process for the bz2 process for a newer version compared to a much older version? Thank You for the reply :) Ron

Comment: Give me a second to actually download and open the file for you, so I can see what it contains.

Comment: Thank You. I am currently on my Windows side not my linux right know I just downloaded as well, but I can't extract it. Windows of course.

Comment: Thank you for downloading it on your side to check it out.

Comment: @RonnieMarlow It may be worth mentioning that the install file says "Don't build from source unless you have to!"

Comment: I don't understand what the" Don't build from source unless you have to"

Comment: @KazWolfe the first part you quoted refers to the library dependencies of GIMP and not GIMP itself, though. And releases, such as 2.8.18, are hardly bleeding edge - the whole stable branch isn't, to be honest. Also, on apt-based systems, running sudo apt-get build-dep gimp is a good way to get all dependencies installed.

Answer (score 1):

Well at first I recommend you to uninstall the older versions of gimp to avoid conflicting as follows

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge gimp
```

extracting tar.bz2 is as follows . If you have downloaded gimp 2.8.8.tar.bz2 then go to the place where you downloaded and open up a terminal there and execute the following:

```
tar -xvjf gimp-2.8.8.tar.bz2 -C /opt/
chmod -R a+x /opt/gimp-2.8.8
cd /opt/gimp-2.8.8
sudo ./install-sh
```

Thats it.